# Kivy Access ids from .kv file to .py file

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

.
I'm new into kivy and I want to make an android app. I almost finish GUI, the front-end part, but I have a very big problem. I've searched all over the internet but without answer. I don't know how to access ids from .kv to use them into .py functions.
I've tried all of what I've found on the internet, but didn't work. I want to access ids from .kv file to work with them. For exemple, I have a profile screen, where user write his first name, and last name, and in the next page I want to show his first and last name by using a function.
Here's the .kv profile page:

```
<Profile>

        FloatLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:(1,1,1,1)
                 
                Rectangle:
                    source:"CreateProfileImg.png"
                    size: root.width, root.height
                    pos: self.pos 
    
    
            Label:
                pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": 1}
                size_hint: 1, .1
                text:"Create your profile"
                font_size: 65
                font_name:"FreeSansBoldOblique-BYJ3.otf"
                color: rgba(247,251,246,255)
                id: profile_label
    
            Label:
                text: "First Name: "
                font_size: 45
                color: rgba(247,251,246,255)
                size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"x":0.20, "top":0.8}
            TextInput:
                id: name
                multiline: False
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.35, "top": 0.8}
                
            Label:
                text: "Last Name: "
                font_size: 45
                color: rgba(247,251,246,255)
                size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"x":0.16, "top":0.7}
            TextInput:
                id: prenume
                multiline: False
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.35, "top": 0.7}
    
    
            Label:
                text: "Currency: "
                font_size: 45
                color: rgba(247,251,246,255)
                size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
                pos_hint: {"x":0.18, "top":0.6}
            Spinner:
                id: moneda
                text:"Select currency"
                color: 0, 0, 0 ,1
                background_normal:"MoneyButton.png"
                size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
                pos_hint:  {"x":0.35, "top":0.6}
                values: ['Ron', 'Euro', 'Dolar','Lira Sterlina']
                sync_height: True
                #on_text: root.currency_clicked(moneda.text)
    
            GridLayout:
                rows:1
                pos_hint:{"top": .2, "left": 1}
                size_hint: 1, .2
                ImageButton:
                    source:"Next_Button_On_Press.png"
                    on_press:
                        self.source = "Next_Button_On_Release.png"
                        app.printname()
                    on_release:
                        self.source = "Next_Button_On_Press.png"
                        app.change_screen("page1")
```

I have more .kv files with lots of ids, but I think if I learn how to work with thise two, next will be easier.
I want to specify that I have a 'main.kv' which contains: 1. name
2.ids
from all over my .kv files. I use those ids to navigate between pages.

Here's the code:

```
#:include homescreen.kv
#:include page1.kv
#:include profile.kv

GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager

        HomeScreen:
            name: "home_screen"
            id: home_screen
        Profile:
            name: "profile"
            id: profile
        Page1:
            name: "page1"
            id: page1
```

Let me explain for the last time what I want to do, maybe will be usefull for you to understand and trying to help me. As you see, into 'profile' I have 3 ids. When get TextInput from user, those ids store the information. I want to use those information into next page, where I want to say **[[[" Hello " + ids]]]**.

```
         So, please help me!! Make me to understand!
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble with this as well when I was first leaning Kivy a couple years back, but I finally figured out the way.  there is a bit of boilier-plate required to maintain the connection.

in this example **my_label** is a kivy id and I am connecting it to a Python object of the same name.  this is done with the line: my_label: my_label

```
<Screen2>:
    # Python: KIVY id(s)
    my_label: my_label
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Screen2"
        MDLabel:
            id: my_label
            text: "-"
```

and in the Python code matching that object there is a line in the class definitionl my_label: MDLabel
which is providing a type hint.  If you are using an IDE such as PyCharm this can help you to have auto-complete in your code according to the object type.

```
class Screen2(Screen):
    my_label: MDLabel

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.my_label.text = "test"
```

and the line self.my_label.text = "test" is of course to show how you can use the object.

you can also do more complicated things such as put multiple items from a kv layout into a list or even a dictionary.
kivy code:

```
    # a list of spinners kv_spinner_list is a ListProperty
    kv_spinner_list: [kv_spinner_0, kv_spinner_1, kv_spinner_2,]
```

and this can be a more organized way to bring multiple items into the Python code.